# unable to get row text in div table from selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The UI which I am automating has tables using div tag. it's displaying same text for all the iterations of table. Please find the html code and my script. Please help.

```html
<div class="panelbody"/>
<div class="hdrInv"
<div class="STable">
<div class="sitezones">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
   <b> Text1</b>
</div>
<div class="hdrInv"
<div class="STable">
<div class="sitezones">
<div class="row">
<div class="col">
   <b> Text2</b>
</div>
<div class="hdrInv"
<div class="STable">
<div class="sitezones">
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <b> Text3</b>
   </div>
</div>
```

Webdriver Code

```
List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'hdrInv')]"));
System.out.println("No of Tables: "+table.size());
for(int tabind=0;tabind<table.size(); tabind++){
    System.out.println("ROWText: "+table.get(tabind).findElement(By.xpath("//div[1]/div[contains(@class,'site-zones')]/div[@class='row']/div[2]")).getText());
}
```

it displays, 
ROWText: Text1
ROWText: Text1
ROWText: Text1

Comment: Please help in what?

Comment: added the expected output in edit

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for this :

```
List <WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'STable')]/div/div[@class='row']"));
            for(WebElement row:rows)
            {
                System.out.println("Text "+row.findElement(By.xpath("div[2]")).getText());
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code.

```
List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'hdrInv')]"));
System.out.println("No of Tables: "+table.size());

for(int tabind=0;tabind<table.size();tabind++)
{
   System.out.println("ROWText: "+table.get(tabind).findElement(By.xpath(".//div[1]/div[contains(@class,'site-zones')]/div[@class='row']/div/b")).getText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

following just might work, haven't tested though.

You need to use `.//` or `./` to find relative element, else i guess it will find element from start, `html`

```
private List<WebElement> table = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'hdrInv')]"));
        System.out.print("No of Tables: "+table.size());
        for(int tabind=0; tabind<table.size(); tabind++){
            System.out.println("ROWText: "+table.get(tabind).findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='col']/b")).getText());
        }
```

Comment: If "getText()" doesn't work, you can get the text by getAttribute("innerHTML")

Comment: I tried this, I get error: Unable to locate element.

Comment: @codefemme which line? put some wait and check, or debug code using berakpoint and check.